# How can I hash data in BigQuery using a pepper and keep the pepper secret?

Tags: hash, google-bigquery

We have Personally Identifiable Information (PII) data (e.g. emailAddress) residing in BigQuery. We do not expose that PII data to our end users (we use [policy tags](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-policy-tags) to hide it) however in order that those users can join different tables together we need to provide a one-way hash of emailAddress.

To increase security our InfoSec team insists that we use a [pepper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper_(cryptography)) to encrypt the data, probably using BigQuery's [sha256 function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hash_functions#sha256). Our challenge is where we store that pepper and how we use it without requiring to write the data into a different table (we absolutely do not want to have to move some data just for the purpose of hashing a column).

We are contemplating this approach: The value that we choose for the pepper is stored in a table in BigQuery that end-users do not have access to. We will provide BigQuery views on top of the raw data that produce the hash, effectively doing this:

```sql
CREATE VIEW view-name AS
SELECT sha256(d.emailAddress + p.PEPPER_VALUE) AS emailAddressHash
, <other columns>
FROM table-containing-data d CROSS JOIN table-containing-pepper p
```

and we will grant end-users access to those views.

Our concerns with this approach are regarding securely storing the PEPPER_VALUE. Given users will be SELECTing from the view the query will be running as that end user. How do we give the view the ability to use the PEPPER_VALUE without giving the end user the ability to see it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set [Authorized Views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorized-views) here is a [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views#objectives) that might be helpful.

> An authorized view lets you share query results with particular users
> and groups without giving them access to the underlying tables

Comment: Ah yes, I was looking at authorised UDFs but I suppose authorised views would do the job too. thanks.